# Curl with POST method gives "HTTP Status 405" while the submit form is a POST. Input doesn't get prefilled from paired URL parameter

Tags: php, url, curl, input, get

I searched around google for a similar problem but couldn't find any, or couldn't formulate my question precisely enough, so I come to you.

I'm trying to login to [forclosure.com](http://forclosure.com) from my localhost using **Curl**.

If you go to [forclosure.com/login](http://forclosure.com/login), you'll find that the login form uses a **POST** method, whereas when I try to login with Curl, it gives me an **HTTP Status 405** error.

I tried to use Curl with a **GET** request instead and it passes *(while the form is a POST..)*.

But now comes another problem, the password input isn't recognized in the URL and the login doesn't pass.

For exemple, if you try those parameters :
[https://www.foreclosure.com/login?**key**=testkey&**password**=testpass](https://www.foreclosure.com/login?key=testkey&password=testpass)

You will see that the username "**key**" gets filled, but not the password "**password**".

Same thing seems to happen with the search bar above with the name "**q**"

Thank you in advance. If the solution seems obvious to you, bear in mind that I'm still learning and would like to be pointed towards the right path.

Comment: Please go read [ask], and [mcve]. // First of all, that form contains a couple of hidden fields, did you send values for those as well? Secondly, that form is not even POSTed _to_ `/login`, but has `action="https://www.foreclosure.com/login.html"` set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe), I decided to try and use *CURLOPT_URL* with [/login.html](https://www.foreclosure.com/login.html) instead of just [/login](https://www.foreclosure.com/login).. and not surprisingly, it works.

But I had to use **GET** parameters with *CURLOPT_POST* on *true*.

Here's the code for the interested:

```
//-----------------------------------Login Part
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.foreclosure.com/login.html?key='.$loginInfo['key'].'&password='.$loginInfo['password'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //Wouldn't work without it
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, NULL);                     //NULL to use cookies in memory, use $cookiefile to store them in disk
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```